# Where are the definitions for Azure Boards work item types?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Azure DevOps currently supports 4 different project processes. One example of a project process is Agile. [Within the Agile process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process?view=azure-devops), Azure Boards supports several different work item types such as `Epic`, `Feature`, `User Story`, `Bug`, `Task`, `Issue`, etc. I would like to use Azure Boards and the work item types but don't have an understanding of the types, exactly what they mean, and the difference between each type.

Where are the formal definitions of these types, and any examples of a use for each work item type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > An epic represents a business initiative to be accomplished. [1]
- > A feature typically represents a shippable component of software. [1]
- A `bug` is a defect in the software
- A `user story` is used to partition a `feature` into workloads that fit into a sprint

  > A good user story should be:
  >
  > “I” ndependent (of all others)
  >
  > “N” egotiable (not a specific contract for features)
  >
  > “V” aluable (or vertical)
  >
  > “E” stimable (to a good approximation)
  >
  > “S” mall (so as to fit within an iteration)
  >
  > “T” estable (in principle, even if there isn’t a test for it yet)
  >
  > [2]
- A `task` is an item to partition a `user story` or a `bug` into smaller workloads
- > An issue is a type of work item that defines an item that you want to track as it may impact the completion of other work. It is defined for the Agile process and doesn't appear on any backlog or board. See [Manage issues and impediments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/manage-issues-impediments?view=azure-devops). [3]

Sources for the quotes:

- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#what-comprises-a-feature-or-epic
- [2] https://www.agilealliance.org/agile101/agile-glossary/
  As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process, the `Agile` process in Azure DevOps is based on Agile methodologies and they link to the website of the Agile Allegiance. They have a glossary [here](https://www.agilealliance.org/agile101/agile-glossary/), where they define an `epic` and a `user story`.
- [3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/agile-glossary?view=azure-devops